# Docker CentOS systemctl

Tags: centos, systemd, docker

I trying to build a CentOS image with systemctl command. But each time **when I build it**. I obtain this error :

```
Step 6/10 : RUN systemctl enable syslog-ng && systemctl start syslog-ng
 ---> Running in 9a8c5a2cdbae
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl enable syslog-ng && systemctl start syslog-ng' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y install vim && \
    yum -y install wget && \
    yum -y install rsync && \
    yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
# Install syslog-ng 3.14
RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/ && \
    wget https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng314/repo/epel-7/czanik-syslog-ng314-epel-7.repo && \
    yum -y install syslog-ng
RUN systemctl enable syslog-ng && systemctl start syslog-ng
RUN yum -y remove rsyslog
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
   systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
   rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
   rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Someone know what I do wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is SELInux enabled, anything relevant in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?

Comment: @sebasth audit log of the Docker Host ?

Comment: SELInux is not install.

Comment: The Dockerfile is read sequentially, so can you try putting your systemctl commands at the end of the file, after the RUN/VOLUME/CMD set of commands?

Comment: @Haxiel Same error

Comment: @DevHugo Thanks for checking. Can you try pulling this systemd-enabled container as your base image instead? [Link](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/)

Comment: @Haxiel I already did it. I just found this answer bellow to solve my issue.

Comment: if you need systemctl inside docker container , it means you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all `systemctl` commands and just run `syslog` as CMD to start it.

```
CMD ["syslog-ng"]
```